# Android - What is the best way to do something every time the time changes?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, timed

I want a do something every time a minute passes, for example when the time changes from 10:38 to 10:39 i want to do something.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Something like what?

Comment: I need to excute a function every time a minute passes

Comment: If you want to do something even if the app is stopped you should use services. Otherwise you can create a timer and map it to the clock time

Comment: Job scheduler will help you

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) ! Please read  [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) !

Answer (score 2):

You need to listen for TIME_TICK via broadcast receiver

```
IntentFilter timeTickIntentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);
registerReceiver(YourReceiver, timeTickIntentFilter);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) for  this.

```
void startSchedulerAlarm() {
    int oneMinute = 1 * (60 * 1000); //Trigger Every 1 Minute
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction(AlarmReceiver.alaramIntent);
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, AlarmReceiver.alarmIntentCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), oneMinute, alarmIntent);

}

void stopSchedulerAlarm() {
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction(AlarmReceiver.alaramIntent);
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, AlarmReceiver.alarmIntentCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarmManager.cancel(alarmIntent);
}
```

Create a receiver for your Alarm in Manifest:

```
    <receiver       
        android:name="{YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME}.AlarmReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:process=":remote">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="{YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME}.alarmIntent"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
public static final String alaramIntent = "{YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME}.alarmIntent";
public static final int alarmIntentCode = 000054310;

private String TAG = AlarmReceiver.class.getSimpleName();

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //Do something Here
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep a **Service** running in the background that keeps on checking for a specidied time, Say you want to do turn the phone to silent mode when it's 10:00 PM. So the service should keep on checking if the time is 10:00 PM and when it is, execute the code to turn the phone to silent mode